# File watcher on a SCSS file

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm completely stumped. I have tried to the best of my being to fix this.

I have a SCSS file, that has a watcher on it, but the watcher does not seem to be working. A normal CSS file is not being made at all. Here is my SCSS file:

[image]

As well, I am using the WebStorm IDE.

Error message:

> An exception occurred while executing watcher 'SCSS'. Watcher has been    disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Luke\WebstormProjects\untitled\myTestWebsite\main.scss" (in directory "C:\Users\Luke\WebstormProjects\untitled\myTestWebsite"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Program path:
[image]

Comment: Dit you install Ruby and the Sass Gem? Did you then point to that gem in the file watcher?

Comment: Yep. Did it twice :P

Comment: Can you tell me what the values are of the fields 'Program' and 'Arguments' in the File Watcher Edit screen?

Comment: Program : C:\Users\Luke\WebstormProjects\untitled\myTestWebsite\main.scss                  Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Program should point to the Sass Gem of Ruby instead you are pointing to your scss file. This is not correct:

Find the sass.bat file on your computer and use the path to that file in the program value

in my case the correct path is: `c:\Ruby22\bin\sass.bat`

[image]

Webstorm automatically watches every scss file you create and creates a css file. You do not need to create a file watcher for every independent scss file

Small detail: I should add  `--style compressed` to the arguments. This creates a minified version of the css file and the load time is decreased

Comment: Ah, yes. But how do I point to Sass Gem of Ruby once I have located the path?

Comment: Add the path to Program field in the edit File Watcher screen (see my screenshot)

Comment: Done, but the CSS file is still not being created.

Comment: Another error? The same error? No error? What is happening now?

Comment: Including this part? ```Cannot run program "C:\Users\Luke\WebstormProjects\untitled\myTestWebsite\main.scss"```

Comment: Yep. And the CSS file still sin't being created. Is there perhaps something I need to update/run?

Comment: When the error message is still the same and it still says that it cannot run the the program ```C:\Users\Luke\WebstormProjects\untitled\myTestWebsite\main.scss``` it means that you did not change the program field in the file watcher edit screen. Or are you looking at old error messages?

Comment: Ok, the settings look ok. Can you go to the scss file in Webstorm press the combination ```Shift->Control->A``` and then type ```Run File Watchers``` and press ```enter```

Comment: I did as you said, and nothing changed. What was supposed to happen?

Comment: The css file should have been created. No message is shown because you have ```show console``` set to ```Error```

Comment: Still no main.css file. There are no errors anymore though, the html launches fine in chrome.

Comment: When the html launches in chrome there has to be a css file somewhere. Maybe have a look in the console (F12) what the location of the css is.

Comment: No, the css file had no effect on the html :/ With the css I was making the text green, but when I launch it, the text is still black.

Comment: I see you have the ```Track only root files``` checked. Try unchecking this. Change ```Show console``` to ```Always``` and try again with ```Shift->Control->A``` please post the output of the console.

Comment: Done, but even when I set Show console to Always, nothing was shown in the console after it ran.

Comment: Try making a change to the file. Add an enter or something. The File Watcher should start then automatically.

Comment: Still nothing. I have no idea what could be happening.

Comment: Then I am afraid I have to give up. Maybe somebody else has an idea.

Comment: I really appreciate it tho, thanks for taking your time to help.

Comment: no problem. Good luck with solving it. Remember to post the solution to this page when you have found it, for future reference

Comment: @WyattLowery Maybe you have more than one File Watcher? Please restart IDE if you have not tried it yet.